# Docker specific settings

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have configurations that are environment specific. For instance, a path that I want to access when debugging the project via IIS, be in C:\MyApp\MyLocation, but when debugging the project in Docker, will be ine \app\something.

My plan was to have a specific appsettings.json for this type of build. So, where I would normally have the C:\MyApp\MyLocation in my appsettings.development.json, I would create a appsettings.docker.json, put the setting in there, and then add/change the environmental variable for "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" to 'docker'.

However, this plan did not work, as I now get this message when I debug my app via Docker :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
> For more information on configuring HTTPS see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.'](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.%27)

Is there any way I can get it work in this manner, or any other way I can docker specific configurations?

Comment: Check https://forums.docker.com/t/running-an-insecure-registry-insecure-registry/8159/9 for more details

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, but I'm unsure that relates to my question? The linked question is regarding insecure registry, and the section you linked to seems to be about MacOS specific solutions. Could you perhaps indicate how this is related?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Actually after re-reading your question and correctly reading the error, I can see that your issue has nothing to do with the configurations.

Your Asp.Net App is configured to use the developer certificate for HTTPS. Either you deactivate by removing the `AddAuthentication` and `UseAuthentication` or you have to install the certificate on the Docker image.

You can use `dotnet dev-certs https` in your DOCKERFILE before running your app temporarily, but in the future should create a real HTTPS certificate and configure your app correctly.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1

---

You've tagged your question with .Net Core, so I guess that you're using it.

If so, you should probably be reading configurations through Configuration providers. And if your application startup is done this way:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

It will load the json configuration provider and then the environment variables configuration provider. This means that any value that you have in your json configuration file can and will be overrided by environment variables that matches the json key correctly.

It's very easy to set environment variables when starting Docker image, and it's usually the preferred way to go when you want to set configuration of Docker images.

The hierarchy is usually set by separating the parts with `__`.

```
set MyKey="My key from Environment"
set Position__Title=Environment_Editor
set Position__Name=Environment_Rick
dotnet run
```

More information on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables).